# function not stopping

Tags: c++

I'm creating a program to input product that asks for `itemName,size,amount,and hour+minute`

everything so far looks good, but when I compile and chose menu "1" which is adding item by pushing the data inputted, it ran `del()` function even though i haven't called it yet and cout `"--- Add New Order Success ---";` didnt show up

also, when I choose menu "2", it successfully printed `"no data available"` but didn't return to `mainMenu` after pressing `"enter"` key

I'm kinda stuck because I don't know what to fix ,searched the questions list in the forum but nothing coded in c++
also, my code doesnt show any error which makes me confused

Feel free to point anything I'm doing wrong ,and I'm using doubly linked list with push pop method in `C` because I don't quite understand using vector which the data are encapsulated in classes.

Much appreciated your help,  Thanks in advance :).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
#define w setw(2)<<flag<<"|"
#define f flag++
#define s cin.sync();cin.clear()
static int flag;

class receiveDate{
public:
    int hour;
    int minute;
};

class item:public receiveDate{
public:
    int jumlah;
    char namaProduk[20];
    int ukuran;
    class item *prev,*next;
};
class item *head=NULL,*curr,*tail;

void clear(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

void header(){
    clear();
    int a = 1;
    cout<<"           ";
    for(int i=0;i<=90;i++){
        int b = i%10;
        if(b==0){
            cout<<a;
            a++;
        }else{
            cout<<" ";
        }
    }
    cout<<endl<<"  ";
    for(int i = 0;i<=9;i++){
        printf("1234567890");
    }
    cout<<endl<<"  ";
    for(int i=0;i<=100;i++){
        printf("=");
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void pop(){
    class item *temp;

    if(head!=NULL){
        if(curr == head)
        {
            head = head->next;
            free(curr);
            if(head != NULL)
            {
                head->prev = NULL;
            }
        }
        else if(curr == tail)
        {
            curr = tail;
            tail = tail->prev;
            free(curr);
            tail->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = head;
            while(temp->next != curr)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            curr->next->prev = curr->prev;
            temp->next = curr->next;
            free(curr);
        }
    }
}

void popall()
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
        curr=head;
        head=head->next;
        free(curr);
    }
}

void display(){
    header();
    int i=0;
    curr=head;
    cout<<w<<setw(22)<<"Item Name"<<setw(8)<<"Ukuran"<<setw(4)<<"Jam Pesan"<<endl;f;
    while(curr){
        i++;
        cout<< w << setw(2) << i <<setw(20) << curr->namaProduk << setw(8)<<curr->ukuran <<setw(4) << curr->hour << ":" << curr->minute;f;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
}
void push(char namaProduk[],int ukuran,int jumlah,int hour,int minute){
    curr=(class item*)malloc(sizeof(class item));
    class item *temp;
    strcpy(curr->namaProduk,namaProduk);
    curr->jumlah=jumlah;
    curr->ukuran=ukuran;
    curr->hour=hour;
    curr->minute=minute;
    if(head==NULL){
        head=tail=curr;
    }else{
        curr->next=head;
        head->prev=curr;
        head=curr;
    }
    head->prev=NULL;
    tail->next=NULL;
}
void add(){
    header();
    flag=1;
    char namaProduk[20];
    int ukuran;
    int jumlah;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    char jenis[10];
    do{
        cout<<w<<"Input nama produk [3-30] : ";f;
        cin>>namaProduk;s;
    }while(strlen(namaProduk)<3 || strlen(namaProduk)>30);
    do{
        cout<<w<<"Input ukuran [1 = kecil, 2 = sedang, 3 = besar] : ";f;
        cin>>ukuran;s;
    }while(ukuran<1||ukuran>3);
    do{
        cout<<w<<"Jumlah item [1 - 999] : ";f;
        cin>>jumlah;s;
    }while(jumlah<1||jumlah>999);
    do{
        cout<<w<<"Jam pesan :";f;
        cin>>hour;s;
    }while(hour<0||hour>24);
    do{
        cout<<w<<"Menit pesan:";f;
        cin>>minute;s;
    }while(minute<0||minute>59);
    push(namaProduk,ukuran,jumlah,hour,minute);

    cout<<w<<"--- Add New Order Success ---";
    cin.get();
}

void del(){
    int tot = 0;
    int pos;
    int qty;
    int i;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"--- There is No Order in The List ---";
    }
    else
    {
        curr = head;
        while(curr)
        {
            tot++;
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        display();
        do
        {
            cout<<" Input Number of The Order [1.."<< tot<<"]";
            cin>>pos;s;
        }while(pos<1 || pos>tot);

        curr = head;

        for(i=1;i<pos;i++)
        {
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        pop();

        cout<<endl<<" --- Take Order Success ---";
        cin.get();
    }
}

void menu(){
    int menu;
    do{
        header();
        flag=1;
        cout<<w<<endl;f;
        cout<<w<<endl;f;
        cout<<w<<endl;f;
        cout<<w<<setw(57)<<"PROGRAM INVENTARIS MINIMARKET"<<endl;f;
        cout<<w<<setw(58)<<"=============================="<<endl;f;
        cout<<w<<"     Pilih Menu:"<<endl;f;
        cout<<w<<"      1. Add Item"<<endl;f;
        cout<<w<<"      2. View Inventory"<<endl;f;
        cout<<w<<"      3. Remove order"<<endl;f;
        cout<<w<<"      4. Remove all order"<<endl;f;
        cout<<w<<"      5. Exit Program"<<endl;f;
        cout<<w<<"      Input Menu: ";f;
        cin>>menu;s;
        cin.sync();cin.clear();

        if (menu =1 ){
            add();
        }else if(menu=2){
            display();
        }else if(menu=3){
            del();
        }else if(menu=4){
            popall();
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while(menu<1||menu>5);
}
int main(){   
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to put `break` at the end of each `case` block. Otherwise execution will continue to the next case block aka "fallthrough". For example `case 2: display(); break; case 3: del(); break;` and so on

Comment: in every case: statements?

Comment: i tried it just now and after it couts "add new order success" and entered
it didnt go back to main menu

Comment: There's way too much code in the question. This could be reproduced with a 5-line `main`. Please provide a [mcve] when asking questions.

Comment: That is because you've got an infinite loop right after switch: `while(menu!=5);`. You should pay attention to compiler warnings and use debugger to figure out what is going on.

Comment: OT: Stuff like `#define w setw(2)<<flag<<"|"` makes your code very hard to read. I would avoid defines but if you really want them, you should give them a reasonable name.

Comment: Note that `strlen(namaProduk)>30` is a bit pointless since the program is already undefined if the user enters more than 19 characters. Use `std::string`.

Comment: Aside: `#define w setw(2)<<flag<<"|"
#define f flag++
#define s cin.sync();cin.clear()`   These are really really nasty; There's a reason 1 letter variables are frowned upon, let alone one letter #defines!  It makes your code completely unreadable and in combination with each other you're just asking to have an `int cin.sync();cin.clear();` line by mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from a bad use of `switch/case`. See [Switch/Case documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch). Your menu `switch/case` will triggered every cases

```
switch(1) {
    case 1 : cout << '1'; // prints "1",
    case 2 : cout << '2'; // then prints "2"
}
```

and

```
switch(1) {
    case 1 : cout << '1'; // prints "1"
             break;       // and exits the switch
    case 2 : cout << '2';
             break;
}
```

Your code should look like this :

```
 switch(menu){
    case 1:
        add();
        break;
    case 2:
        display();
        break;
    case 3:
        del();
        break;
    case 4:
        popall();
        break;
    }
```

With this code you won't need a `while` at the end of your `switch`. Your while loop is infinite because if you type `1`, it will triggered `add()` menu again and again because `while(menu!=5);` is always true unless `menu=5`

Comment: You should also address the OP's misunderstood `while` after the `switch`, it's part of the question.

Comment: if i removed the while loop, wont it cause the program to exit after doing add/view/del?
i wanted the program to keep doing menu 1/2/3/4 until it gets "5"as input to exit the program

Comment: Why would you want a `switch/case` then ?

Comment: If you want to execute 1/2/3/4 then exit don't need to use a `switch/case`, just write them without a`switch/case`. `switch/case` are used to execute one thing corresponding to a user input. If in all cases you want your functions to be triggered no need to use a `switch/case`